# spring boot native image cannot run due to config file inside third-party lib

Tags: graalvm, spring-native

I'm trying spring native with a small boot project which depends on opensaml, there are two config files inside the opensaml jar,
[image: opensaml jar]

and the lib loads the config file by

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resource)
```

the native image failed to start due to missing the resource, then I searched some posts and added

```
<buildArgs>
    <arg>-H:IncludeResources=".*"</arg>
</buildArgs>
```

in native-maven-plugin's configuration, but still failed to load the resource.

any advice? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Graalvm provides [native image agent](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/Agent/), after building the jar of the project just run with agent which will generate all required configuration

```bash
java -agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=./graalcnf/ -jar target/demo-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

[Here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/test-microservice-frameworks/blob/main/ktor-demo/resources/META-INF/native-image/com.mascix/ktor-demo/native-image.properties) is a working example config for ktor. And [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/test-microservice-frameworks/blob/main/ktor-demo/graalcnf/resource-config.json) is how agent generated resource configuration.

Also [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html#native-image.advanced.known-limitations) says

> If you find a library which doesn’t work with GraalVM, please raise an issue on the reachability metadata project.

You may need to open ticket at https://github.com/oracle/graalvm-reachability-metadata